# How to share the \Mongo instance between Doctrine ODM and MongoDbSessionHandler?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use MongoDB to store my sessions, and I need to get a reference to the `\Mongo` instance.

But apparently it's not declared as a service. Instead, doctrine creates it from within the wrapper.

So what can I do about it? I tried this:

```
services:
    mongo.connection:
        class: MongoDoctrine\MongoDB\Connection
        factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager
        factory_method: getConnection
    mongo:
        class: Mongo
        factory_service: mongo.connection
        factory_method: getMongo
```

But sometimes it returns null, and it also conflicts with my logger preprocessor that adds the request_id to the logs, which I think has something to do with the session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source for [Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Connection.php), the `getMongo()` method simply returns the `$mongo` class property, which may or may not be initialized. If possible, you can call `initialize()` manually before you inject the connection. Given that you're already defining a service for the Connection wrapper, you should be able to do this:

```
services:
    mongo.connection:
        class: Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection
        factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager
        factory_method: getConnection
        calls:
            - [initialize, []]
    mongo:
        class: Mongo
        factory_service: mongo.connection
        factory_method: getMongo
```

That would invoke the `initialize()` method between the container constructing the `mongo.connection` service from its factory method and it being returned.

Some additional points to note:

1. If `mongo.connection` is only going to be used once (to injected into `mongo`), you may prefer using anonymous service definitions in lieu of defining another service.
2. The ODM bundle already defines each connection as `doctrine_mongodb.odm.%s_connection`, using its name from the configuration in place of `%s`; however, that's not helpful if you need to add a method invocation to the service definition.
3. The latest version of the ODM bundle (for Symfony 2.1+) changed its service prefix from `doctrine.odm.mongodb` to `doctrine_mongodb.odm`, although a BC alias exists for the default document manager. It'd be wise to switch over to the new prefix, though.

Comment: This worked, though I'm still getting a circular reference when using the preprocessor for monolog.

Comment: Okay I solved this by injecting `@service_container` into my SessionRequestProcession, instead of injecting `@session`. This way it won't be instantiated until needed. By that time it will already exist, and will avoid the circular reference. I know we are not supposed to inject the container, but I don't see any other solution unless they declare Mongo as a service so we can use it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your Connection service depends on Monolog as an option? In the case of a circular reference, injecting the container and fetching the service you need lazily (often to avoid circular references) is perfectly alright. Symfony2 does this internally in a number of core classes out of necessity.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm not sure where the circle starts, but it definitely has something to do with Monolog trying to get the request_id (which doesn't happen by default, I added that through a processor - **SessionRequestProcessor*, I made a mistake in my second comment). So it might be something like Monolog -> Session -> Mongo -> Doctrine -> Monolog.